# Change text once in a week

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need a script that will allow automatic updates of the text(a sentence) once in a week.

For example, I have 7 texts, text1, text2, text3 , .....text7.

I need text1 to be displayed for one week (from Monday to Sunday).

On next monday text2 should be displayed and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens in Week 8? Should multiple users all see the same text as each other, or does it depend on when each individual first visited your page? **What have you tried?** (Hint: a combination of `onload`, `setTimeout()`, and `localStorage` can help you here.)

Comment: In week 8 text1 should be displayed and it should work as a loop.

Comment: It does not depend on individual users ,all users see the same text.

Comment: Then you will have to use server-side code to keep track of which week it is.

Answer (score 2):

you can't do it in javascript because this is client side activity and for updation also user have to open his window continuously for 7 days. If he closed his window then again it will start from point 0  . for this you have to run cron job .......

Comment: *"you can't do it in javascript "* - Then why is your example JavaScript? (Also, did you actually *run* your example?)

Comment: I have found this script working,  It changes tip according to date. [link text](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/tipday.shtml) and it uses javascript only

Answer (score 0):

```css
.your_text{
  
  color : <?php echo $colors[$currentWeekNumber] ?>;
  }
```

```html
<php
     
     $currentWeekNumber = date('W');
   
 $colors = array("#FFF"/*White*/, "#28937D"/*Dark Green*/, "#FFF"/* White*/, "#FFF"/*White*/, "#FF8B53"/*Orange*/, "#FFF"/*White*/, "#000"/*Black*/);
  
?>
  
  

     <div id="container">
       <span class="your_text">My Text</span>  
     </div>
```

You have to include your **CSS** in **.php** file. so that it gets the value of color along with its day.

**PS** : Change your array values according to your color value for particular day.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to change the text once in a week.In your code, text changes color according to the day .

Comment: updated answer. check now.